# Power Supply for Stepper Motor Stop Motion Camera Rig

Tags: power-supply, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

Apologies in advance for this being a somewhat meandering question. I've read all the forums I can find on this and other sites but still feel I need a little direct assistance; if you feel this is redundant or too broad a question, I understand if you can't respond.

I'm working on building a camera slider to use for stop motion animation and need help understanding the power supply I'll need for the stepper motor(s). I'm going to base the project on this slider system from OpenBuilds:

> https://openbuildspartstore.com/v-slot-nema-17-linear-actuator-bundle-belt-driven/

which optionally includes this nema 17 stepper motor:

> https://openbuildspartstore.com/nema-17-stepper-motor/

with the following specs:

- 2 phase
- Peak Current is 1.68A/phase
- 1.65 ohm/phase
- 12-24VDC (Recommended)

I'll be connecting it to an Arduino Uno and an A4998 (or similar) driver. My initial build will only need one motor, but I'd like to be able to add 2 or 3 additional motors/drivers down the line. As this is for stop motion animation, the motors needs to be able to move precisely, but not quickly.

My (admittedly limited) understanding is that for one motor, a 12 volt 5A power supply should be sufficient (and safe for me to handle), and that if I were to run 3 identical motors off the same supply I would need a 12 volt 15A supply. For whatever reason a 15A circuit makes me a bit nervous. In truth, the motor above might be overkill for what I need. There are other motors with lower amperage (and lower torque) that might suffice, like this one:

> https://tinkersphere.com/3d-printer-parts/1885-nema-17-stepper-motor-with-detachable-wires-48v.html

which is rated at

- 12 volt
- 0.4 A (I'm not sure from the specs if this is per phase or total)
- 30 ohm

I gather three of those motors could run off a 12v 3A supply. It's also my understanding that there is no issue providing excess amperage to a build, only excess voltage. I also understand that the stepper driver will control the amount of current delivered to the motor.

So, my question boils down to: am I doing this math correctly? Am I significantly better off or safer using the lower amp motors and a smaller circuit? Have I missed anything crucial?

Comment: 5 amps seems like a lot; how powerful of a stepper motor is this? Or are you just talking about the startup current?

Comment: @Hearth Well, the more powerful motor is rated at 1.68 amps/phase, so with two phases that gets up to 3.36amp (hence the 5, I figured that was a rounder number and would be easier to locate). As I said that might be more powerful a motor than I really need to move a camera around though... Do you think the smaller motor would suffice?

Comment: Probably. The 1.68 amps may also be a stall current, not the running current.

Comment: Yeah, probably want a difference stepper motor since the camera should slide without much friction. For first option, I think the current per phase is the minimum current where minimum voltage per phase would be 1.68*1.65 ≈ 2.8V, so at the recommended 12V much more current.
Suggest to use lower current stepper motor, another alternative is ROB-10846